# Coq strict positivity is puzzling

Tags: coq

I'm working on a development with a language with terms, variables, and nat literals, where the arity of language constructs in predefined:

```
Inductive sort : Set := TERM | VAR | NAT.

Inductive termArity : list sort -> Set :=
  | Var    : termArity [VAR]
  | Let    : termArity [VAR ; TERM ; TERM]
  | Lam    : termArity [VAR ; TERM]
  | Ap     : termArity [TERM ; TERM]
  | NumLit : termArity [NAT]
  | Plus   : termArity [TERM ; TERM]
  .
```

The definition of a term I'd like to use contains one child matching each type in its arity specification (hlist is heterogeneous lists from CPDT):

```
Inductive t : Type :=
| Node : forall (sorts : list sort) (code : termArity sorts),
    hlist (fun s : sort => match s with
                           | TERM => t
                           | VAR => String.string
                           | NAT => nat
                           end) sorts
          -> t.
```

But coq rejects it with 'Non strictly positive occurrence of "t"'.

As expected, replacing the `t` in the definition with `nat` convinces coq that it's okay:

```
Inductive t : Type :=
| Node : forall (sorts : list sort) (code : termArity sorts),
    hlist (fun s : sort => match s with
                           | TERM => nat
                           | VAR => String.string
                           | NAT => nat
                           end
          ) sorts
    -> t.
```

As does, surprisingly, always returning `t`.

```
Inductive t : Type :=
| Node : forall (sorts : list sort) (code : termArity sorts),
    hlist (fun s : sort => t) sorts
    -> t.
```

Why does my attempted definition fail, while this passes the positivity checker? How can I fix my definition?

Edit: another attempt which forgoes the codes but fails due to universe inconsistency:

```
Definition var : Set := String.string.

Inductive termArity : list Type -> Type :=
  | Var    : termArity [var]
  | Let    : termArity [t; t]
  | Lam    : termArity [var; t]
  | Ap     : termArity [t; t]
  | NumLit : termArity [nat]
  | Plus   : termArity [t; t]

with t : Type :=
| Node : forall (sorts : list Type) (code : termArity sorts),
    hlist (fun s : Type => s) sorts -> t.
```

Whole file:

```
Require Coq.Bool.Bool. Open Scope bool.
Require Coq.Strings.String. Open Scope string_scope.
Require Coq.Arith.EqNat.
Require Coq.Arith.PeanoNat.
Require Coq.Arith.Peano_dec. Open Scope nat_scope.
Require Coq.Lists.List. Open Scope list_scope.
Require Coq.Vectors.Vector. Open Scope vector_scope.
Require Fin.

Module Export LocalListNotations.
Notation " [ ] " := nil (format "[ ]") : list_scope.
Notation " [ x ; .. ; y ] " := (cons x .. (cons y nil) ..) : list_scope.
Notation " [ x ; y ; .. ; z ] " := (cons x (cons y .. (cons z nil) ..)) : list_scope.
End LocalListNotations.

Module Core.
    Set Implicit Arguments.

    (* cpdt heterogeneous lists *)
    Section hlist.
      Variable A : Type.
      Variable B : A -> Type.

      Inductive hlist : list A -> Type :=
      | HNil : hlist nil
      | HCons : forall (x : A) (ls : list A), B x -> hlist ls -> hlist (x :: ls).

      Variable elm : A.

      Inductive member : list A -> Type :=
      | HFirst : forall ls, member (elm :: ls)
      | HNext : forall x ls, member ls -> member (x :: ls).

      Fixpoint hget ls (mls : hlist ls) : member ls -> B elm :=
        match mls with
          | HNil => fun mem =>
            match mem in member ls' return (match ls' with
                                              | nil => B elm
                                              | _ :: _ => unit
                                            end) with
              | HFirst _ => tt
              | HNext _ _ => tt
            end
          | HCons x mls' => fun mem =>
            match mem in member ls' return (match ls' with
                                              | nil => Empty_set
                                              | x' :: ls'' =>
                                                B x' -> (member ls'' -> B elm)
                                                -> B elm
                                            end) with
              | HFirst _ => fun x _ => x
              | HNext _ mem' => fun _ get_mls' => get_mls' mem'
            end x (hget mls')
        end.
    End hlist.

    Arguments HNil [A B].
    Arguments HCons [A B x ls].

    Arguments HFirst [A elm ls].
    Arguments HNext [A elm x ls].

    Module Exp.
      Inductive sort : Set := TERM | VAR | NAT.

      Inductive termArity : list sort -> Set :=
        | Var    : termArity [VAR]
        | Let    : termArity [VAR ; TERM ; TERM]
        | Lam    : termArity [VAR ; TERM]
        | Ap     : termArity [TERM ; TERM]
        | NumLit : termArity [NAT]
        | Plus   : termArity [TERM ; TERM]
        .

      (* coq complains this is not strictly positive. *)
      Inductive t : Type :=
      | Node3 : forall (sorts : list sort) (code : termArity sorts),
          hlist (fun s : sort => match s with
                                 | TERM => t
                                 | VAR => String.string
                                 | NAT => nat
                                 end) sorts
                -> t.

      (* exactly the same definition, but replacing t with nat, is
         not flagged as non-strictly-positive. this makes sense to me. *)
      Inductive t_not_quite_1 : Type :=
      | Node1 : forall (sorts : list sort) (code : termArity sorts),
          hlist (fun s : sort => match s with
                                 | TERM => nat
                                 | VAR => String.string
                                 | NAT => nat
                                 end
                ) sorts
          -> t_not_quite_1.

      (* this also (like the failed definition) returns t in the
         hlist type, but surprisingly typechecks! I don't understand
         how this is different *)
      Inductive t_not_quite_2 : Type :=
      | Node2 : forall (sorts : list sort) (code : termArity sorts),
          hlist (fun s : sort => t_not_quite_2) sorts
          -> t_not_quite_2.
    End Exp.
End Core.
```

Comment: Does your universe inconsistency go away if you replace `var : Set` with `var : Type `?

Comment: It becomes an anomaly: 'Anomaly "A universe comparison can only happen between variables." Please report at http://coq.inria.fr/bugs/.'

Comment: What version of Coq are you using?  Does it say that in 8.7.1?  If so, it's a bug that should be reported on GitHub

Comment: Thanks -- the upgrade from 8.7.0 to 8.7.1 fixed the anomaly. It now just reports a universe inconsistency.

Comment: What if you also replace `[nat]` `[nat : Type]`?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I see where the universe inconsistency comes from now and it is genuine.

Comment: Or, rather, it is a result of not having a cumulative polymorphic list type?  Because you pass `sorts` to `termArity`, the universe of `Type` in the two `list Type`s (one in `termArity : list Type -> Type` and one in `sorts : list Type`) must be identical. Because `t` must be big enough to hold this this of types, the universe of `t` must be strictly larger than the universe of the `Type` in `sorts : list Type`. However, since you insert `t` into the list passed to `termArity ` in some of its constructors, the universe of `t` must not be larger than the universe of `Type` in `list Type`. Boom!

Comment: I need to work on improving the speed of the universe-checker in my head.  In any case, if you `Set Universe Polymorphism`, does that fix your universe inconsistency?  The other way to do it is to replace `termArity sorts` with `termArity (List.map (fun x => x) sorts)`, I think.  (I might be wrong about this; I can't recall if the `Type` in `list Type ` contributes to the universe of `termArity`.  If it does, then you're sunk, at least without polymorphism you are, because you place `termArity` in `t` and you place `t` in the list and you place the list `t`, and that's a loop.)

Comment: Neither `Set Universe Polymorphism` nor `List.map` fixed the universe inconsistency, but I have made good progress with the inductive type you gave in your answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coq does not see through match statements in the positivity checker; this is a long-standing feature request, see https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/4701 and https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/1433.

I believe that it will work if you turn it into an inductive:

```
Inductive kind_of_sort t : sort -> Type :=
| term_kind : t -> kind_of_sort t TERM
| var_kind : String.string -> kind_of_sort VAR
| nat_kind : nat -> kind_of_sort NAT.
```

and then use this in place of the `match` statement.